# How can you add 2 joins in a subquery?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get information from 3 tables in my database. I am trying to get 4 fields. 'kioskid', 'kioskhours', 'videotime', 'sessiontime'. In order to do this, i am trying a join in a subquery. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT k.kioskid, k.hours, v.time, s.time
FROM `nsixty_kiosks` as k
LEFT JOIN (SELECT time
FROM `nsixty_videos` 
ORDER BY videoid) as v
ON kioskid = k.kioskid LEFT JOIN
(SELECT kioskid, time
FROM `sessions` 
ORDER BY pingid desc LIMIT 1) as s ON s.kioskid = k.kioskid
WHERE hours is NOT NULL
```

When I run this query, it works but it shows every row instead of just showing the last row of each kiosk id. Which is meant to show based on the line `'ORDER BY pingid desc LIMIT 1'.`

Any body have some ideas?

Comment: Please show your table structure, what your current query produces, and what you'd like to see produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of joining to `s`, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT k.kioskid,
       k.hours,
       v.time,
       ( SELECT time
           FROM sessions
          WHERE sessions.kioskid = k.kioskid
          ORDER
             BY pingid DESC
          LIMIT 1
       )
  FROM nsixty_kiosks AS k
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT time
           FROM `nsixty_videos` 
          ORDER BY videoid
       ) AS v
    ON kioskid = k.kioskid
 WHERE hours IS NOT NULL
;
```

N.B. I didn't fix your `LEFT JOIN (...) AS v`, because I don't understand what it's trying to do, but it too is broken; the `ON` clause doesn't refer to any of its columns, and there's no point in having an `ORDER BY` in a subquery unless you also have a `LIMIT` or whatnot in there.

Comment: Thanks I just didn't add a limit to my v query. Adding the limit worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your join on the 'v' subquery doesn't actually reference the 'v' subquery, nor does the 'v' subquery even contain a kioskid field to `JOIN` on, so that's undoubtedly part of the problem.

To go much further we'd need to see schema and sample data.